# RabbitMQ will not start, form size greater than binary?

Tags: rabbitmq

I've googled for the line that's the issue and found nothing, I really need some help

"beam/beam_load.c(916): Error loading module inet:\n  form size 44416 greater than size 12280 of binary\n"

```
~$ sudo rabbitmq-server 

{error_logger,{{2014,3,6},{17,0,40}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{'EXIT',{undef,[{inet,udp_options,[[{port,0},{recbuf,8192}],inet]},{inet_udp,open,2},{inet_config,set_hostname,0},{inet_config,init,0},{inet_db,start_link,0},{supervisor,do_start_child,2},{supervisor,start_children,3},{supervisor,init_children,2}]}}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,inet_db},{mfargs,{inet_db,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2014,3,6},{17,0,40}},"~s~n",["beam/beam_load.c(916): Error loading module inet:\n  form size 44416 greater than size 12280 of binary\n"]}
{error_logger,{{2014,3,6},{17,0,40}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a broken install of Erlang, I had to purge erlang (which unfortunately removed rabbitmq) then I reinstalled via apt and everything returned to normal.

I also took the opertunity to update to the latest version via the Erlang solutions repo